# Copy specific data from sheet to sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, copy, classification, text-classification, data-transfer

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mpALs4rdNj-TFFgCQ0CEBP453v-FfQJR_bBxOzQakWU/edit#gid=1256640730

I have a "masterlist" sheet collect data from **Google Forms** and I need the script to ***copy*** the data from master list to the related sheet according to their "Location".

`Example 1`

> **Sheet 1: Contain all the data (Master List)**
> *Name......Address...............................Location*
> Rose.......21,Radje Road,88888.........Kedah
> Rose.......21,Radje Road,88888.........Kedah
> Rose.......21,Radje Road,88888.........Penang
> Stone......5,Jae Road,22222...............Penang

> **Sheet 2: Copy data from Sheet 1 (Location-Kedah Only)**
> *Name......Address...............................Location*
> Rose.......21,Radje Road,88888.........Kedah
> Rose.......21,Radje Road,88888.........Kedah

> **Sheet 3: Copy data from Sheet 1 (Location-Penang Only)**
> *Name......Address...............................Location*
> Rose.......21,Radje Road,88888.........Penang
> Stone......5,Jae Road,22222.........Penang

> 

`Example 2`

> **Sheet 1: Contain all the data (Master List)**
> *Name.....Gender*
> Bryan.....Male
> Mei.....Female
> Lily.....Female
> xx.....Female
> xx.....Male

> **Sheet 2: Copy data from Sheet 1 (Gender-Female Only)**
> *Name.....Gender*
> xx.....Female
> Lily.....Female
> Mei.....Female

> **Sheet 3: Copy data from Sheet 1 (Gender-Male Only)**
> *Name.....Gender*
> Bryan.....Male

```
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getSheetByName('Master List');
  const shsr=2;//data start row on master list
  const shhr=1;//master list header row
  const hA=sh.getRange(shhr,1,1,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
  const vs=sh.getRange(shsr,1,sh.getLastRow()-shsr+1,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  const base='Sheet';
  let shts=ss.getSheets();
  shts.forEach(function(s,i){if(s.getName()!='Master List'){ss.deleteSheet(s);}});//delete all other sheets
  const gvs=sh.getRange(shsr,7,sh.getLastRow()-shsr+1,1).getValues().map(function(r){return r[0]});
  const s=new Set(gvs);
  const g=[...s];//g has unique values now
  g.forEach(function(v,i){
    let nsh=ss.insertSheet(base + String(i+1),i+1);
    let aA=[]
    aA.push(hA);//start with header row
    vs.forEach(function(r,j){
      //compare to column G value
      if(r[6]==v) {
        aA.push(r);//add rows that match
      }
    });
    nsh.getRange(1,1,aA.length,aA[0].length).setValues(aA);
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();//not really necessary but fun to watch the progress
  });
}
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from `I need the script to duplicate / transfer / copy the data to another sheet by classification in column G "Location" to the related new sheet.`, I cannot understand about your goal and the current issue of your script. So can I ask you about them? For example, how about explaining your script by adding it to your question? It seems that your sample Spreadsheet has the script.

Comment: I'm sorry it was my poor English... What I need is actually "Copy" the data from my Master List to the new sheet with specific Location.

Comment: I will explain by using another example, see whether you get what I means..

**Sheet 1: Contain all the data (Master List)**
Bryan      Male
Mei         Female
Lily         Female
xx           Female
xx           Male

**Sheet 2: Copy data from Sheet 1 (Female Only)**
xx       Female
Lily     Female
Mei     Female

**Sheet 3: Copy data from Sheet 1 (Male Only)**
Bryan    Male

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding more information. About your script in your shared Spreadsheet, I thought that to explain your current issue using your current script will help users think of the solution. How about this?

Comment: I don't have any script for this yet, because I have no idea what to do to get this result...

Comment: Kindly take a look at these questions here since they offer explanations on how to copy data from one sheet to another: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48691872/google-apps-script-copy-data-to-different-worksheet-and-append), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44967086/).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function copyDataUniqueToColG() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getSheetByName('Master List');
  const shsr=2;//data start row on master list
  const shhr=1;//master list header row
  const hA=sh.getRange(shhr,1,1,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues().map(function(r){return[r[1],r[2],r[3],r[4],r[5],r[6]]})[0];
  const vs=sh.getRange(shsr,1,sh.getLastRow()-shsr+1,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  const base='Sheet';
  let shts=ss.getSheets();
  //shts.forEach(function(s,i){if(s.getName()!='Master List'){ss.deleteSheet(s);}});//delete all other sheets
  const gvs=sh.getRange(shsr,7,sh.getLastRow()-shsr+1,1).getValues().map(function(r){return r[0]});
  const s=new Set(gvs);
  const g=[...s];//g has unique values now
  g.forEach(function(v,i){
    let sA=[];
    ss.getSheets().forEach(function(obj){sA.push(obj.getName())});
    if(sA.indexOf(v)==-1){ss.insertSheet(v);}
    let aA=[]
    aA.push(hA);//start with header row
    vs.forEach(function(r,j){
      //compare to column G value
      if(r[6]==v) {
        aA.push([r[1],r[2],r[3],r[4],r[5],r[6]]);//add rows that match
      }
    });
    let dsh=ss.getSheetByName(v);
    dsh.getRange(1,1,aA.length,aA[0].length).setValues(aA);
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();//not really necessary but fun to watch the progress
  });
}
```

Comment: Hi Cooper, thank you so much for your reply, but it is not working for me.. And the function that I need is actually copy the data from master list to the related sheet according to their "Location".

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mpALs4rdNj-TFFgCQ0CEBP453v-FfQJR_bBxOzQakWU/edit#gid=1256640730

You may edit the script using this shared spreadsheet.

Comment: My "master list" is used to collect all the customer database from different place, and you can see my other sheet like "Penang","Perak","Negeri Sembilan","Melaka","Johor,"Johor Bahru","Kedah", is still empty, So I need the function to copy the customer data from master list to these sheet according to their "Location".

Comment: I tested this and it works for me. Also I will not follow links to spreadsheets. Everything that you need in your question must be posted in the question . Don’t depend upon external links. What does not working for me mean?

Comment: It didn't work for copy & paste the source from "Master List" to other sheet...

Comment: Sorry I don't know what to tell you it works for me

Comment: Is it your script only copy data in one column? Maybe there's some misunderstanding through my explanation because I am not very good in english. Actually I need to copy the (complete data) in *whole column* instead of just one column.

Comment: Can you share me your example spreadsheet link? I'll try to figure it out..

Comment: How about showing me an image of the master list and a few of the pages

Comment: And post the code you have now at the end of your question

Comment: Oh so the names of the page come from column G

Comment: Okay I think that is what you wish.