# onEdit() specific cell doesn't fire the script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I am trying to copy data from one sheet to another, when I change the value of one cell in the source sheet. I had this problem with other scripts that I tried to fire when editing a specific cell as well, not sure what I am doing wrong.

I found this code here ([Google Apps Script - Copy data to different worksheet and append](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48691872/google-apps-script-copy-data-to-different-worksheet-and-append)) that works well when I run it manually however when I wrap it so that when editing one cell nothing seems to happen, see below.

```
  if (e.range.getA1Notation() === 'C1'){
 var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1ws8yg5_1k4ZZN2amfZ-cNvY-hUMUDGhbwnNPCGJhlAY'); //replace with source ID
 var ss = sss.getSheetByName('export'); 
 var range = ss.getRange('B3:C8'); 
 var data = range.getValues();

 var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('152JxdVi6Ssqz2ZZ65yDW5p5m0PnP63vApNgfP3jS_Pc'); //replace with destination ID
 var ts = tss.getSheetByName('import'); //replace with destination Sheet tab name

 ts.getRange(1, 2, 6,2).setValues(data); //you will need to define the size of the copied data see getRange()

}
}
```

Source Sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ws8yg5_1k4ZZN2amfZ-cNvY-hUMUDGhbwnNPCGJhlAY/edit#gid=0

Destination Sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/152JxdVi6Ssqz2ZZ65yDW5p5m0PnP63vApNgfP3jS_Pc/edit#gid=0

I tried to with creating a new trigger as well, something like this:

```
function createOnEditTrigger() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(targetSpreadsheetID);
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("CopyRange")
    .forSpreadsheet(ss)
    .onEdit()
    .create();
}
```

but nothing is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Explanation / Issue:

There are 2 things to note here:

- You forgot to pass the event object as a parameter of the `CopyRange(e)` function. Without this parameter, the event object can't be used but your code uses it.
- Indeed you need an installable trigger because of `SpreadsheetApp.openById()`. You can indeed also create the trigger with the script you mentioned and this is also my recommended approach.

### Solution:

Go to the `export` spreadsheet, clear the previous code and add this code. Essentially, I am adding the event object into the `CopyRange(e)` function and the trigger creation function. Then execute **only** the `createOnEditTrigger` function:

```
function CopyRange(e) {
  if (e.range.getA1Notation() === 'C1'){
 var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1ws8yg5_1k4ZZN2amfZ-cNvY-hUMUDGhbwnNPCGJhlAY'); //replace with source ID
 var ss = sss.getSheetByName('export'); 
 var range = ss.getRange('B3:C8'); 
 var data = range.getValues();

 var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('152JxdVi6Ssqz2ZZ65yDW5p5m0PnP63vApNgfP3jS_Pc'); //replace with destination ID
 var ts = tss.getSheetByName('import'); //replace with destination Sheet tab name

 ts.getRange(1, 2, 6,2).setValues(data); //you will need to define the size of the copied data see getRange()

}
}

function createOnEditTrigger() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1ws8yg5_1k4ZZN2amfZ-cNvY-hUMUDGhbwnNPCGJhlAY');
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("CopyRange")
    .forSpreadsheet(ss)
    .onEdit()
    .create();
}
```

[image: example]