How to copy selected data from Sheet 1 to Sheet 2 when press a button on Google Sheet?
Select data row from Sheet 1 then press submit to copy to Sheet2


Table on Sheet2 already contains data.
Select Data from Table on Sheet1 by checkbox.
Press the submit button.
Add selected data from Sheet1 to Table on Sheet2.


https://stackoverflow.com/a/48692527/5514747

Does this answer your question? Google Apps Script - Copy data to different worksheet and append

try:
function moveDataBasedOnTrue() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var destinationSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  
  // Define the ranges
  var sourceRangeStr = "B2:C";
  var conditionRangeStr = "A2:A";
  var destinationRangeStr = "A:B";
  
  // Get the data range in Sheet1 columns B and C
  var sourceRange = sourceSheet.getRange(sourceRangeStr);
  var conditionRange = sourceSheet.getRange(conditionRangeStr);
  var sourceData = sourceRange.getValues();
  var conditionData = conditionRange.getValues();
  
  // Prepare an array to hold the rows to be moved
  var rowsToMove = [];
  
  // Iterate through each row in the data
  for (var i = 0; i < conditionData.length; i++) {
    // Check if the condition in column A is TRUE
    if (conditionData[i][0] === true) {
      // Add the corresponding row (columns B and C) to the rowsToMove array
      rowsToMove.push(sourceData[i]);
    }
  }
  
  // Determine the last row in the destination sheet
  var lastRow = destinationSheet.getLastRow();
  
  // Append the rows to move to the destination sheet
  if (rowsToMove.length > 0) {
    destinationSheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 1, rowsToMove.length, rowsToMove[0].length).setValues(rowsToMove);
  }
}

where you bind moveDataBasedOnTrue() to your button

I forgot to mention some conditions, but with a little bit of adaptation, it's working perfectly fine. Thank you.
