App script to copy all data from Workbook A to Workbook B, appending to first blank row not working correctly
I modified a script I found to copy data from the 'Data' tab of workbook A to the 'LookerData' tab of workbook B, but need it to add continuously to the 'LookerData' tab with no blank rows between.
The first time I run it, copies fine. But everytime I run it after that it starts the data 27 rows below the last entry. Why is it not starting at the first empty row?
data format
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mzAizqlyEGfhKH6DJdNCMXvsAH9JxihVHucOsJNvd2A/edit?usp=drivesdk
`// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48691872/google-apps-script-copy-data-to-different-worksheet-and-append
// Copies to Row 2 of target sheet the first time  and then appends to first blank row.

function CopyRange() {
 var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(’SpreadsheetA ID’); //replace with source ID
 var ss = sss.getSheetByName('Data'); //replace with source Sheet tab name
 var range = ss.getRange(2, 1, ss.getLastRow(), ss.getLastColumn()); //assign the range you want to copy
 var data = range.getValues();

// Logger.log(data);

 var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(‘SpreadsheetB ID’); //replace with destination ID
 var ts = tss.getSheetByName('LookerData'); //replace with destination Sheet tab name

 ts.getRange(ts.getLastRow()+1, 1,ss.getLastRow(), ss.getLastColumn()).setValues(data); 

}
`


Welcome to SO! Please share your data examples as a text table instead of via an image. Please share a copy of your spreadsheet without sensible data; you can use this tool to create an anonymous template. Please show the errors you get.

Waiting to see the error you get, but you're saying you're hitting the maximum amount of rows permitted by Google Sheets!?

Yes, it that 1000000 max cells

Ok I'm guessing that's not a full "copy" of your data, so lets get straight to the point: is there by chance some random row at the bottom of the sheet (say, row 7954) with some value? In other words, what numerical value does the getLastRow method return?

Ok I've just re-read your question: what do you mean by "need it to add continuously"? How many times are you executing your function? Do you have some sort of trigger?

I'm transferring the data from another spreadsheet on a monthly bases, so when the the next months data is copied, I want it to start at the bottom of the previous data, no blank rows in between. Just triggering the script manually.

How can I determine the value getLastRow is returning? I'm selecting the entire sheet and deleting everything between test runs so no random data should be there. My most resent test showed a 40 row data set was being place 27 rows below the previous data set. I don't understand what's controlling the getLastRow?

Ok, I think I finally figured out what was going on. My source sheet had array formulas at the top which apparently affects getLastRow. Once I deleted those formulas, the script worked as needed.

if you've solved the issue, please share it as an answer. You can answer your own questions and even accept the former if you want.

My source sheet had array formulas at the top which apparently affects getLastRow It is more the case that it can affect getlastRow; it really depends on the specific arrayformula. Also, if there is data that is NOT populated by arrayformula, then there are alternatives to getLastRow - e.g. see this answer: Determining the last row in a single column

I think I have finally worked out the problems by learning some things the hard way. Please correct me if any of these assumptions are wrong. The getLastRow being wrong due to array formulas in some of the columns went away after I made sure both the source and destination sheets had the same number of columns and started with the same number of rows (1000). Then I made sure the data for both started in Row2 with Row 1 being the header. (Data was starting in Row3 with Row 2 being blank). Script is now working as needed. Thx to all.
